# Connections on Bundles with Trivial Determinant

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, connections, gauge-theory

I want to let $E$ be a rank $n$ complex vector bundle on a smooth manifold $X$.  A connection $\nabla$ gives us a way of differentiating local or global sections of $E$.  We define it to be a $\mathbb{C}$-linear sheaf morphism

$$\nabla : \Omega^{0}(E) \longrightarrow \Omega^{1}(E),$$

satisfying the Leibniz rule $\nabla(f \cdot s) = f \cdot \nabla(s) + s \cdot df$ for all local section $s$ and local complex functions $f$.  A connection $\nabla$ induces a connection (which we also call $\nabla$) on $\text{det}(E) = \bigwedge^{n}E$

$$\nabla: \Omega^{0}(\text{det}(E)) \longrightarrow \Omega^{1}(\text{det}(E))$$

Now, assume $E$ has a trivial determinant; in other words $\text{det}(E)$ is isomorphic to the trivial line bundle on $X$.  Now my question is, does it follow from what I said above that there exists sections $s_{1}, \ldots, s_{n}$ of $E$ such that $\nabla(s_{1} \wedge \ldots \wedge s_{n})=0$, or is this rather a condition we should impose in the definition of a "compatible connection" with the triviality of $\text{det}(E)$?

I'm leaning towards this being an additional property one may ask for.  If you look at the Leibniz rule, this seems equivalent to asking the induced connection on $\text{det}(E)$ to coincide with the exterior derivative.  In other words, we are asking that $\nabla$ induce the trivial connection on the trivial bundle $\text{det}(E)$.

**EDIT:** My motivation for this question comes from the book "Instantons and Four-Manifolds" by Freed and Uhlenbeck.  On Page 30 (in the second edition) they are briefly introducing the standard notion of a connection on a complex vector bundle.  They mention that if the bundle has a hermitian metric, you would ask a connection to additionally satisfy the usual compatibility condition.  If the metric is Hermitian, this breaks the structure group down from $GL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ to $U(n)$.  To get to $SU(n)$, you also need the determinant to be trivial.  So...they write:

*"If, in addition, the group of the bundle is $SU(n)$, then we require the existence of orthonormal local sections $\sigma_{1}, \ldots, \sigma_{n}$ for which*

$$\nabla(\sigma_{1} \wedge \ldots \wedge \sigma_{n})=0"$$

Comment: Do you mean that $X$ is a complex manifold? Otherwise, I do not know what $O_X$ is.

Comment: Ah yeah, I'm too used to writing that from the complex setting.  I just mean the determinant line bundle is trivial (on an arbitrary smooth manifold).  Thanks, I'll change it.

Comment: Certainly $\det E$ can be trivial without your having global sections $s_1,\dots,s_n$ of $E$ to give a nowhere-vanishing global section of $\det E$. (For example, take $E=\mathscr O(k)\oplus\mathscr O(-k)$ on $\Bbb P^N$.) I presume you mean to ask that there be a nowhere-vanishing global section of $\det E$ that is parallel.

Comment: I see now what I said was silly; would my question make more sense if I said $s_{i}$ were local sections of E instead?  In other words, if the determinant is trivial, does it necessarily have parallel sections locally, or is this some additional compatibility condition you would have to impose?

Comment: Unless your connection  is flat, you will not have local parallel sections.

Comment: hmm, right.  Yeah, I'm quite puzzled now.  You know how upon introducing a Hermitian metric, there is a compatibility condition on a connection to be Hermitian.  In a book on gauge theory and four-manifold by Uhlenbeck, it is mentioned that if the bundle also has trivial determinant, you must have orthonormal local section $\sigma_{1}, \ldots, \sigma_{n}$ such that $\nabla(\sigma_{1} \wedge \ldots \sigma_{n})=0$.  But perhaps one won't have this in general.

Comment: So please give a precise statement of all the hypotheses in play in the case of Uhlenbeck's assertion.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yeah, sorry I should have included that originally.  I added an edit above.  Thanks for your comments.